# Rotating a wavefunction to get an exponential of $L^2$ and $L_z$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators, wavefunction, rotation

With the canonical choices of directions etc, assuming the quantum mechanical wavefunction $\Psi$ is an eigenfunction of the angular momentum operator $L_z$, we can express a rotation of angle $\alpha$ around the $z$-axis in terms of an exponential of $L_z$:

$R_z(\alpha)\Psi=\exp(-i\alpha L_z)\Psi$.

Further assuming that $\Psi$ is an eigenfunction of $L^2$, is there a rotation (potentially including all three directions) that lead to an exponential of $L^2$ (and possibly $L_z$)?

I assumed there would be a way to express a general rotation in this way, i.e. something like

$R_x(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\gamma)\Psi=\exp\big(-if(\alpha,\beta,\gamma,L^2,L_z)\big)\Psi$,

where $f$ is linear in $L_z$ and $L^2$, but I haven't been able to find it.

Note that the question is not about finding an expression for the general rotation but about finding *any* rotation that can be expressed as an exponential that includes $L^2$ and possibly $L_z$ but no other operators or powers of these (and nothing like $0\cdot L^2$).

Also, if it exists, getting the rotation in terms of spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$ is great if that is easier.

Comment: I don't understand the question. A rotation of angle $\alpha$ around the $i$-th axis is *always* given by the exponential $\exp(\mathrm{i}\alpha L_i)$, no matter what state it acts on.

Comment: True, but I'm looking for a rotation that will lead to an exponential that looks something like $\exp(i(\alpha L^2+\beta L_z))$ where $\alpha$ is nonzero.

Comment: You cannot do this. The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff lemma guarantees that for $X,Y$ elements of a Lie algebra, $exp(X)exp(Y) = exp(Z)$ where $Z$ is also an element of the Lie algebra. $L^2$ is not an element of the Lie algebra $SO(3) = span(L_x,L_y,L_z)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what quite what you are trying. Rotations are generated by the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$. That is, any rotation matrix can be expressed as $R(\theta_x,\theta_y,\theta_z) = \exp(\theta_x L_x + \theta_y L_y +\theta_z L_z)$ where the $L_i$ are elements of the algebra. This means that for any $X,Y$ in the Lie algebra, $e^X e^Y = e^Z$ where $Z$ is also an element of the algebra. This fact is known as the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula).

$L^2 = L_x^2 +L_y^2 +L_z^2$ is not an element of the Lie algebra. It is a hermitian operator, but its exponential doesn't have any generally accepted meaning (though you might see it in the time-evolution operator if it appears in the Hamiltonian).

You might be interested in the [Wigner D Functions](http://www.theoretical-physics.net/dev/math/wigner.html). If $\Psi$ is a vector or spinor with $L^2 = j(j+1)$, then it has components corresponding to different $L_z$ eigenvalues. If $\Psi$ has components $\Psi_s$ then the components after the rotation $R_z(\alpha)R_y(\beta)R_z(\gamma)$ are 
$\Psi'_{s} = \sum_{t} D^{(j)}_{s,t}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) \Psi_t$. (Note, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are Euler angles, slightly different from the angles you define)